# detecting iPad in javascript without using user-agent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, user-agent, browser-detection

I have a javascript code that I don't want it to run on iPads.
is there a way to detect an iPad using javaScript ***without using user-agent***.

say for example using the device width as we do it for css.

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {/* For general iPad layouts */}
```

Thanks in advance,
R

Comment: Short of testing capabilities and finding some unique combination that applies only to ipads (and hope it stays relatively consistent between each new version), there's nothing you can do to reliably detect a particular device without testing the UA via javascript. And even then the UA could be changed.

Comment: Is the browser version specific to iOS? That may be a start...

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to test using user-agent?

Comment: You could use the CSS media query to give some hidden element a different "z-index" value based on which query succeeds. Then you could check the style with ".css()" ...

Comment: I'm always a bit perplexed when there are strange restrictions such as these.

Comment: @Brad user-agent testing is pretty complicated to do right. Now, when you're looking for just one device, maybe not .. except oops!  there are two iPads now!  There are lots of other tablets too, and there's no reason to treat those users (with real money in their wallets) differently from your iPad users.

Comment: @Pointy, I completely agree with the fact that you shouldn't be treating other tablets and similar devices differently.  Surely RazielH has a specific reason for wanting to detect just iPads?  Or maybe not.  Personally, I'd make it the same for no matter which device hit it, unless there was a specific reason not to.

Comment: well, mainly because I was tasked to do it with something other than user-agent.

Comment: I think it was to make it future proof !!!??? but that brings out another question that will ipads screen sizes always stay the same? if we are going to do it only with screen size detection. and aren't out there other devices with this screen size?

Comment: anyways thanks for the help. I really like the css trick though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use that media query, it's a bit hacky but you can set a style attribute to a predefined element (for example your body), read that with javascript and respond to it.

HTML Head

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) { #tester { border-color: #f00; } }
```

HTML Body

```
<body>
<div id="tester" style="display: none"></div>
```

JS

```
if(document.getElementById('tester').style.borderColor == '#f00') {
   // iPad
}
```

A bit hacky but you can tidy it up a bit if you really want to do it this way; I do prefer checking user agents though ;)

Comment: Won't actually work - you need to use ".currentStyle", not ".style", and that only works in IE.  However your basic approach will work - it'd be possible to let jQuery do the work of getting the current style.

Answer (score 0):

Does `navigator.platform` count as User-Agent-String? You could use:

```
var is_iPad = navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") != -1 ;
```

Comment: This is no more working as of iOS 13.